# How to optimize django-rest-framework serializers with multiple queryset at SerializerMethodField()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django-rest-framework, and I have a project where I have to optimize the response time of an existing API endpoint. Using django-debug-toolbar, found some ways to use prefetch_related() to lessen the SQL queries. The problem is I found that the design of the serializer is to have multiple SerializerMethodField to get its statistics values and using prefetch_related only works on all() but on the second serializer method field with filter() is still being queried for every Class loop. You may see sample code below(this is not the specific code but something like this).

serializer.py:

```
class ClassStatisticsSerializer(ModelBaseSerializer):
    total_sessions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    activity_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_sessions(self, instance):
        sessions = instance.classactivity_set.all()
        date = self.context.get('date')
        if date:
            sessions = sessions.filter(date=date)

        if len(sessions) == 0:
            return None

        return sessions.count()

    def get_activity_count(self, instance):
        activities = instance.classactivity_set.filter(is_present=False)
        date = self.context.get('date')
        if date:
            activities = activities.filter(date=date)

        if len(activities) == 0:
            return None

        return activities.count()

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = (
           'id',
           'batch',
           'type,
           'total_sessions'
           'activity_count'
        )
```

views.py:

```
class ClassStatisticsList(APIView):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          queryset = Class.objects.all().prefetch_related('classactivity_set')
          serializer = ClassStatisticsSerializer()
          return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In here, when I check the SQL queries on the django debug toolbar, get_total_sessions was being queried once on the SQL but get_activity_count was not since this is another query request on the SQL and being queried for every Class loop. For now, making a new model is out of the question so i am stuck on how to properly prefetch the second query request. Hope you can suggest possible way to resolve this. Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) the count for the objects with queryset and then pass it through serializer class initialization. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

condition = {}
if date:
    condition = {'date':date}

queryset = Class.objects.all().annotate(
    total_sessions=Count(
        'classactivity',
        filter=Q(**condition),
        distinct=True
    ),
    activity_count=Count(
        'classactivity',
        filter=Q(**condition)&Q(classactivity__is_present=False),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

Then you need to remove `SerializerMethodField`s from your serializer, a simple IntegerField should be suffice to get the data from queryset without addional db hits:

```
class ClassStatisticsSerializer(ModelBaseSerializer):
    total_sessions = serializers.IntegerField()
    activity_count = serializers.IntegerField()
```

Comment: thank you for your response @ruddra, is annotating queryset done at views.py? Again thank you very much.

Comment: tried the code but experience an error on is_present=False at activity_count that say cannot resolve keyword. is_present is an available table for classactivity_set

Comment: it also affects the filtering of the date. it returns server error once applied for date filtering.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, which should fix is_present issue. But what error do you get with `date` filter? Can you add the full error in your question please?

Comment: Hi @ruddra. Thank you very much. I have also already resolve the date issue by setting the condition to condition = {'classactivity__date':date}. The only problem now is that I need to return None/null instead of 0 if there is no activity. how do we condition it? Again thank you very much.